# Number division leading to even number

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, integers

I am facing a problem where I have to pick an even integer number X in the vicinity of another number Z (say X>=Z). Now I would like to generate a sequence of numbers according to

Y(i) = X(i)/2 + 2

X(i) = Y(i)

and loop over this for some given number of times (say n). How do I pick X(0) such that Y(i)s are even numbers?

Comment: Do you mean $x_{i+1}=\frac {x_i}2 +2$  (not sure what the point of introducing $y_i$ is).

Comment: @lulu yes. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I don't understand the preamble.  Speaking very roughly, $x_n\sim \frac {x_0}{2^n}$ so unless $x_0$ is big, the goal is impossible.    Still, just to say, taking $x_0=2^{n}+4$ gives you $n$ even numbers in a row, and it is easy to find similar seeds.

Comment: Should have said:  any seed of the form $x_0=4+2^{a_1} + 2^{a_2}+ \cdots +2^{a_k}$ will work so long as $a_i≥n$.  If you range is large enough you might be able to find a starting number of this form in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work backwards. Suppose that, for a fixed $n$,  you choose $x_n$ to be an even number. Then:

$$
\begin{align}
x_{n-1} & = 2 x_n - 4 \\
x_{n-2} & = 2 x_{n-1} - 4 \\
\cdots \\
x_1 & = 2 x_2 - 4 \\
x_0 & = 2 x_1 - 4
\end{align}
$$

Multiplying each equation $x_i = 2 x_{i+1}-4$ by $2^i$ and adding all together telescopes to:

$$
x_0 = 2^n\,x_n - 4\,(2^n-1)
$$

This gives the starting value $x_0$ which results in $x_n$ after $n$ iterations, and the relations above ensure that all $x_i$ in between are even integers.

Comment: seems like x(0) can be greater than x(n)?

Comment: @user6386155 Yes, in fact it *will* be larger than $x_n$ whenever $x_n \gt 4$.

Comment: but the series must decrease from x(n) to x(0)

Comment: @user6386155 No. The sequence actually decreases from $x_0$ to $x_n \gt 4$, or is constant if $x_n=4$.

Comment: ok..sorry.. I am a programmer..got used to think in the decreasing direction of a series